# What tools exist to manage an M:TG tournament?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament

I work in an office with a good number of Magic players. I'd like to try and organize some sort of pauper cube style tournament that could be run like a "season" over the course of a couple months. With people meeting once for a long time for a draft and then having games against each other as they have time for the tournament. Maybe with a small buy in for a prize at the end. Are there any tools to manage that kind of thing?

Ideally something to take a lot of the paperwork off of my hands.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the [Wizards Event Reporter](http://wpn.wizards.com/en/wer) can handle casual events. I don't have access to a machine where I can test this though.

Comment: That seems pretty focused on store owners.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit of an outside idea, but this website:

https://us.leaguerepublic.com/gaming.html

is what our local store uses for their MTG leagues, and it works pretty well. Its also free (to a point) but looks like what you're looking for.

Otherwise, a whiteboard displayed in a publicly visible place can work great too.